# What's the best possible way to do this kind of dict matching in python?

Tags: python

I need to create a report which has values taken from data but data sometimes can have certain keys and sometimes won't. So rather than a straight forward manner of checking each key in data dict, and then storing it in report mapped to the particular key.

Is there a better way of doing it?

```
def create_new_report(self, data):
 #data is a dict
 if "value" in data:
  report["value"] = data["value"] # I don't want to do this for all the keys.
```

Value is some key that I know exists in data. To give an example, I might send data as:

```
{"value": 1, "value_2": 2, "value_3": 3}
```

or I might send it as `{"value":1}` and nothing else. So, report by default should have all 3 keys: `value`, `value_2`, `value_3`. But in the second case, where only one key is there, it should take the value and leave rest as `None`.

Comment: From where the `"value"` come from?

Comment: Value is some key of data. Similarly, there will be multiple keys, which will also be present in report. The idea is that if the key is present in data, it should be copied to report.

Comment: If it's  *some key of data* so why you do `if "value" in data`?

Comment: Do you want to copy all keys/values from `data`, or specific ones?

Comment: @Kasra Value is some key that I know exists in data. To give an example, I might send data as {"value": 1, "value_2": 2, "value_3": 3} or I might send it as {"value":1} and nothing else. So, report by default should have all 3 keys: value, value_2, value_3. But in the second case, where only one key is there, it should take the value and leave rest as null.

Comment: If you know it exists why are you checking for it?

Comment: @IamH1kc Please add this explanations in your question! with your example input and expected output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just read your comment which clears things up a bit. Something like this would do the job, I would think:

```
for key in ['value', 'value_1', 'value_2']:
    report[key] = data.get(key, None) # or just data.get(key), since None is the default
```

Answer (score -1):

So if you want to use all the "value"'s from data, you can get all the keys from data through the built-in function for dictionaries keys()

So you can do:

```
for data_value in data.keys():
    report[data_value] = data[data_value]
```